# Why researchers don't study the parameterizations of the problems unlikely to be NP-Hard?

Tags: complexity-theory

I have seen the parameterization of the very well known problems like vertex cover, hitting set etc which are NP-hard (NP-complete precisely). Many researchers in the past have been studied the parameterization of these problems. My question is why researcher's don't study the  parameterizations of the problems unlikely to be NP-Hard?

Comment: Do you mean with the fixed parameter tractability approach?  Considering other parameters like the optimal solution size or maximum degree in the running times of algorithms, instead of just the problem size $n$?

Comment: yes fixed parameter tractability approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not true, there is a program known as "FPT inside P" where we look for interesting parameterizations for problems inside P. The results are perhaps indeed more scattered as opposed to FPT for hard problems which you tend to see much more.

For example, look at the work of Niedermeier and others [1,2] for graph matchings. There is also work for longest path on interval graphs [3]. You will find more by looking at papers that reference the ones mentioned.

---

[1] [Korenwein, Viatcheslav, André Nichterlein, Rolf Niedermeier, and Philipp Zschoche. "Data Reduction for Maximum Matching on Real-World Graphs: Theory and Experiments." In 26th Annual European Symposium on Algorithms (ESA 2018). Schloss Dagstuhl-Leibniz-Zentrum fuer Informatik, 2018.](http://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2018/9516/pdf/LIPIcs-ESA-2018-53.pdf)

[2] [Mertzios, George B., André Nichterlein, and Rolf Niedermeier. "The power of linear-time data reduction for matching." Schloss Dagstuhl–Leibniz-Zentrum für Informatik, 2017.](http://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2017/8116/pdf/LIPIcs-MFCS-2017-46.pdf)

[3] [Giannopoulou, Archontia C., George B. Mertzios, and Rolf Niedermeier. "Polynomial fixed-parameter algorithms: A case study for longest path on interval graphs." Theoretical Computer Science 689 (2017): 67-95.](http://dro.dur.ac.uk/21953/1/21953.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

Most problems that aren't NP-hard are in P, so they're trivially fixed-parameter tractable.

That only leaves NP-intermediate problems such as graph isomorphism and integer factoring, or the possibility of using tighter notions of FPT, such as fixed-parameter linearity.

Comment: I thought the OP was looking for cases where the fastest known algorithm is, say, $O(n^2)$, but this drops to $O(kn)$ where $k$ is some parameter like maximum degree of a graph.  E.g. the usual algorithm for computing the edit distance between two strings of lengths $n$ and $m$ takes $O(nm)$ time, but there's also an $O(dn)$-time algorithm, where $d$ is that (initially unknown) edit distance.

Comment: @j_random_hacker That's what I meant by "fixed-parameter linearity": the running time for parameter $k$ is $O(f(k)\,n)$ for some function $f$ (the identity function, in your example).

Comment: Sorry, I missed that!